# abcdefg.com resolves to 127.0.0.1. Why?

Tags: domain-name-system, localhost

This domain abcdefg.com doesn't use to resolve to anything. Suddenly it started to resolve to 127.0.0.1. I can see this happen in my corporate network, my home network and even on my mobile network.

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: ... Because that's where the domain owner pointed it to...

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, i already got the answrr. The domain is parked with sedoparking.com and looks like its dns record was modified lastweek to point to localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Because whoever owns the domain changed DNS. It's their domain, they can do that.

[MXToolbox query](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3Aabcdefg.com&run=toolpage) confirms it resolves to 127.0.0.1 with a TTL of 24 hours.